# Why MII interface needs two clock TXCLK and RXCLK where as RMII needs only one clock REFCLK

Tags: ethernet

I was reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface) article and Learned that MII interface needs two clocks TXCLK and RXCLK whereas RMII interface needs only one clock. Is there any benefit of having two clocks? If yes what is the limitation of RMII interface then?

Comment: @DAS are you talking about on the PHY? Because I've implemented RMII interfaces on 100MHz processors...

Comment: @DAS that is not true, you don't need a GHz CPU or MPU for RMII. I recall using 120 MHz Cortex-M3 for MII and RMII.

Answer (score 2):

While related, they are different Media Independent Interface standards between Ethernet MAC and PHY.

MII : When transmitting, the PHY uses the local clock for the MII TX clock (and for the MAC) to send data, and when receiving, the PHY locks on to the received data stream and synthesizes the reception clock so the PHY sends the data with recovered MII RX clock to MAC. So the MAC reception is asynchronous to the system clock and it needs to handle it, as the clocks of different devices will not be identical due to allowed tolerances.

RMII : There is a single RMII clock between MAC and PHY, so the RMII interface and MAC are synchronous. Again the single RMII clock is used for transmission, but to allow clock tolerances, the PHY must recover the reception clock and buffer the data in a FIFO in order to send the data over the single clock to MAC.

RMII means Reduced MII and it has half the data path width so the clock is doubled to get same throughput, and some of the synchronizing signals are combined or just used multiplexed or otherwise slightly differently to reduce the interface pin count even further.

Comment: both RX and TX clocks in MII are generated by PHY, not by MAC

Comment: @MCG true, that is how both TX and RX clocks go from PHY to MAC. I did not remember that, as I recall in one project the PHY did not have a crystal of it's own, but it got the master clock from MCU that contained the MAC which is synchronous to the TX clock sent back to MAC. And sometimes I've connected MIIs or RMIIs in reverse or back-to-back configuration which is not always supported.

Comment: @Justme, In your answer, I am not able to understand the when you say, "when receiving, the PHY locks on to the received data stream and synthesizes the reception clock so the PHY sends the data with recovered MII RX clock to MAC. So the MAC reception is asynchronous to the system clock and it needs to handle it, as the clocks of different devices will not be identical due to allowed tolerances." Could you please explain this in simpler terms? Also, I am just learning about the CDR concept. Please simply it for me if you could by editing your answer.

Comment: What terms are too complex? Do you understand how UART works, and that the communication still works and can transfer bytes even if one device uses 1% faster baud rate than the other? Same thing as a concept.

Comment: @Newbie it means you don't get to make up an RX clock, you have to use the sender's clock, so the PHY outputs the sender's clock

Comment: @Justme, thank you for your comment. I never knew that UART will work if one device uses a faster baud rate than the other. Could you please tell me or refer me some links where these knowledge bits are given? Also, I was not clear and didn't understand how you said that one is asynchronous and the other in synchronous in your above answer. Could you please explain that portion?